# warning when executing npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install

After installation of npm (version 4.1.2 on Windows 10) I executed "npm install". But I get the following warning:

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0
>   (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Any ideas why?

Comment: It clearly says it: the fsevents package is not supported on Windows, only on Darwin, so it was not installed. Carry on.

Comment: Sami is right: do not fear the warning message! `wanted` and `current` objects holds the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that the fsevents is module for OS X environment only. Probably your package.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json was created/updated on OS X and you are running `npm install` on a different OS, where fsevents should be omitted.